# Having trouble with spread/pivot wider from long with varying data types

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

```
tst <- data.frame(ID = c(123, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124), 
              Identifier = c("S2", "S2", "S5", "S3", "S2", "S2"),
              Speed = c(15,24,11,34,13,15),
              Box_loc = c(801,802,803,801,802,803),
              Ord = c(86,87,90,81,82,84))
```

I have been attempting to flip the above data from long to wide format, however whenever i try to research it myself, the data does not look similar enough for me to be able to translate it properly. And it seems like it should be a simple solution, but maybe I am missing some critical details.

| ID | Identifier(801) | Speed(801) | Ord(801) | Identifier(802) | Speed(802) | Ord(802) | Identifier(803) | Speed(803) | Ord(803) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | S2 | 15 | 86 | S2 | 24 | 87 | S5 | 11 | 90 |
| 124 | S3 | 34 | 81 | S2 | 13 | 82 | S2 | 15 | 84 |

I want to get my data to look like this table. The actual data has more than just 2 ID's (if that matters), and the numbers in the headers are the Box_loc. So in other words, for each Box_loc, there are IDs from 123-250 which each need their own row with these columns. My actual file has 10 columns or so, but the syntax should be about the same.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the following solution:

```
library(tidyr)

tst %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Box_loc, 
              values_from = !c(ID, Box_loc), 
              names_glue = "{.value}({Box_loc})")

# A tibble: 2 x 10
     ID `Identifier(801)` `Identifier(802)` `Identifier(803)` `Speed(801)` `Speed(802)`
  <dbl> <chr>             <chr>             <chr>                    <dbl>        <dbl>
1   123 S2                S2                S5                          15           24
2   124 S3                S2                S2                          34           13
# ... with 4 more variables: Speed(803) <dbl>, Ord(801) <dbl>, Ord(802) <dbl>, Ord(803) <dbl>
```

Comment: That's really a great answer. Pivoting more than one column is often too complex for my brain. +1

Comment: Thank you dear Martin. It is actually interesting when you set the `names_from` to `Box_loc` and `values_from` to all other than `ID` and `Box_loc`, the names of new columns will be a combination of the values of  `Box_loc` and the old column names where that value located. You are being humble and nice again. This is super simple solution.

Comment: Woke up and realized I havent voted much of your work. Will try to upvote as much as I can

Comment: Thank you very much dear @onyambu that's my pleasure. These days I am mostly working with Python at work and try to answer some very basic questions about it. But you will remain one of my greatest inspiration in programming who would make a mockery of our code with just one line. I owe you big time.

Comment: Hahaha *mockery with one line* thats funny. And maybe by just using the base functions. Anyway I do respond to python questions to. Probably havent met your question

Comment: @onyambu I remember took a great liking to base R recently it's very original and brilliant. But then I totally fell for Python however, for me both do the same job in data science, still what I learned in R helped me to excel faster in Python. I haven't answer many questions in Python but will do soon :D